# SPSS: Create links/anchors in syntax

Tags: syntax, hyperlink, spss

Is there a way to create links or anchors within SPSS syntax? Something like linking to a bookmark.

I am making changes and additions to a syntax file, and document these changes at the bottom of the file as comments. In these comments I would like to link to the part of the syntax that was changed. Now I just write the line number, but that changes as I add more syntax, so the reference becomes incorrect.

Bookmarks were the closest thing I found to what I want to do, but I can't turn them into a link. Moreover, I can only create a maximum of 9 bookmarks, which is not enough.

Comment: why cant you comment in between the code where you did the changes instead? or just small notes in the top with dates and changes? another way to would be saving the syntax in different versions i.e syntax_v1. I'm not aware of any linking in spss sytnax

Comment: My aim is to create an overview of the changes, so others can easily see what I changed and where. I am indeed saving different versions now, but I liked the idea of having just one document rather than many different versions.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to think creatively here:
instead of bookmarking all the changes, you could break up your syntax into many small syntaxes - each of which contains one of the parts where a change was made.
you can name and number the small syntaxes accordingly.
Then you create one syntax which contains a series of INSERT commands, which calls each of the small syntaxes in turn. You can add titles and remarks between the insert commands, so other users can follow the process and study the relevant small syntax that they need separately.

Answer (score 1):

The Statistics Syntax Editor supports bookmarks - you can have up to 10.  Generate a few in the SE and save the syntax file to see how these are represented (hint: look at the COMMENT BOOKMARK lines.

Comment: I noticed the bookmarks, they offer only a partial solution because I can create only 10. This still forces me to create a new version of my syntax whenever I want to make (and refer to) more than 10 changes.

Can you please elaborate on your hint? I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. Do you refer to the bookmark numbers in the sideline?

Comment: Referring to COMMENT, I was just pointing out that that is the mechanism for creating  bookmarks.  You are limited to 10 per syntax file, though, so you might want to break up your syntax into more separate files.  Beyond that, the only mechanism would be to add regular comments in the body of the file.